# Complex sentence on HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I would like realize the following sentence on HQL. could someone help me to translate the SQL sentence to HQL?
select distinct device.description from device, attribute where attribute.deviceid = 1 and device.nodeid = 1
Thanks in advance!
Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my try:

```
select distinct Device.description from Device d 
inner join Attribute 
where d.nodeid = 1
```

I supposed your classes have been named conventionally and your relation is like this:

attribute.deviceid = device.nodeid

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to add something after the inner join? Like "on attribute.device = device.node" (or "fetch attribute.device" if the request was on attibute?) (i guess the entity attributes doesn't have the "id suffix" here)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the strict equivalent of from x,y is a cross join and not an inner join. 
But the result would be the same.